# Selecting multiple elements using QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

In Qt 4.7.1, I'm trying to select multiple elements using QGraphicsItemGroup. The goal is to select all of the elements in the group when one is selected.

If I create the objects individually, I set the ItemIsSelectable flag in the constructor and I add them to the scene I can select them (individually) without problem.

.. but when I create the group, add the items to it and then add the group to the scene, I can no longer select my items. What could be the problem ?

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtGui/QtGui>

class CustomElipse : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    CustomElipse (const QRectF& rect) : QGraphicsEllipseItem(rect) {
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;

    QGraphicsItemGroup * myGroup = new QGraphicsItemGroup();
    CustomElipse *elipse1 = new CustomElipse(QRectF(30, 30, 15, 25));
    CustomElipse *elipse2 = new CustomElipse(QRectF(70, 70, 25, 15));

    myGroup->addToGroup(elipse1); myGroup->addToGroup(elipse2);
    scene.addItem(myGroup);

    QGraphicsView view(&scene); view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `QGraphicsItemGroup` selectable, too:

```
QGraphicsItemGroup * myGroup = new QGraphicsItemGroup();
myGroup->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true); // add this line
...
```

This lets you select the whole group.

Comment: oh, I missed that! Thank you Martin!